# how to get value member of item in checklistbox

Tags: vb.net

This is my code. 'XXXXXXX' is supposed to be the value member of item in checklistbox, but i dont know how to get it. What am i supposed to write there?

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To deptClb.Items.Count - 1
            If (deptClb.GetItemChecked(i)) Then
                MsgBox(deptClb.GetItemChecked(i).ToString)
                cmd = New SqlCommand("if not exists( select * from Institutes_Departments_junction  where department_id =@deid  and institute_id =@inid )  begin insert into Institutes_Departments_junction(department_id, institute_id) values(@deid, @inid) End", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("inid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = institute_id
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("deid", XXXXXXXXX)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
                cmd = New SqlCommand("  Delete  from Institutes_Departments_junction  where department_id =deid  and institute_id =inid end", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("inid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = institute_id
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("deid", XXXXXXXXX)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next
```

i know of another approach  which works for checked items but it is not sufficient since i need to do something for unchecked items as well. and its like this.

```
For Each checkeditem As DataRowView In deptClb.CheckedItems
            cmd = New SqlCommand("if not exists( select * from Institutes_Departments_junction  where department_id =@deid  and institute_id =@inid )  begin insert into Institutes_Departments_junction(department_id, institute_id) values(@deid, @inid) End", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("inid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = institute_id
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("deid", checkeditem(deptClb.ValueMember))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
```

So how do i get the value members of both checked and unchecked items ?

Comment: Is this Winforms or what?

Comment: If my answer didn't solve your problem please comment and explain why it didn't work and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 3):

Just change your loop to iterate over the [**`Items`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection instead.

```
For Each item As DataRowView In deptClb.Items
```

Examining the [**documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx) or the properties that IntelliSense shows you when typing `deptClb.` would've given you the answer quite easily.